# Feign client building URL using app name instead of hostname

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

In a nutshell:

feign client tries to call http://MyApp/endpoint instead of http://10.0.1.24:8080/endpoint

I have an application with instances in AWS registering to an Eureka server and a feign client on the same Eureka server trying to communicate with the application (server is also client of itself if you will).

This is an sample of the /eureka/apps output on the server:

```
<application>
        <name>JSAPI</name>
        <instance>
            <hostName>10.0.1.24</hostName>
            <app>JSAPI</app>
            <ipAddr>10.0.1.24</ipAddr>
            <status>UP</status>
            <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
            <port enabled="true">8080</port>
            <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
            <countryId>1</countryId>
            <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.AmazonInfo">
                <name>Amazon</name>
                <metadata>
                    <public-ipv4>52.91.157.255</public-ipv4>
                    <accountId>831427253318</accountId>
                    <local-hostname>10.0.1.24</local-hostname>
                    <public-hostname>ec2-52-91-157-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com</public-hostname>
                    <instance-id>i-1f86e68c</instance-id>
                    <local-ipv4>10.0.1.24</local-ipv4>
                    <instance-type>m4.large</instance-type>
                    <vpc-id>vpc-3c5e155b</vpc-id>
                    <ami-id>ami-ee5737f9</ami-id>
                    <mac>0e:3c:e0:fa:3f:1c</mac>
                    <availability-zone>us-east-1a</availability-zone>
                </metadata>
            </dataCenterInfo>
            <leaseInfo>
                <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
                <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
                <registrationTimestamp>1478146401223</registrationTimestamp>
                <lastRenewalTimestamp>1478152383740</lastRenewalTimestamp>
                <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
                <serviceUpTimestamp>1478146378932</serviceUpTimestamp>
            </leaseInfo>
            <metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
            <homePageUrl>http://10.0.1.24:8080/</homePageUrl>
            <statusPageUrl>http://10.0.1.24:8080/info</statusPageUrl>
            <healthCheckUrl>http://10.0.1.24:8080/health</healthCheckUrl>
            <vipAddress>JSAPI</vipAddress>
            <secureVipAddress>JSAPI</secureVipAddress>
            <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
            <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1478146401223</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
            <lastDirtyTimestamp>1478110734306</lastDirtyTimestamp>
            <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
        </instance>...
```

The client code is like so:

```
@FeignClient("JSAPI")
public interface JsapiCustomerClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/customers")
    public void createCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerConfig customer);
}
```

I get the following error when trying to execute the method:

```
Connection refused executing POST http://JSAPI/customers
```

I expected it to try and call POST http://10.0.1.24:8080/customers

Any clue? This works on my local, fails once in the cloud.

Thanks

EDIT: Adding pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.knetikcloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>clustermanager</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>clustermanager-server</artifactId>
    <name>clustermanager-server</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.knetikcloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>clustermanager-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-acm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Packages the application to run in Elastic Beanstalk -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>assembly/beanstalk.xml</descriptor>
                    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <description>A Eureka server paired with JSAPI apps specific status endpoints. The server is used to manage instance and customer status within a JSAPI cluster.</description>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your dependencies?

Comment: What dependencies?

Comment: of you application (pom.xml or build.gradle)

Comment: That doesn't have any versions of spring-cloud in it. What do you have config server and eureka server together?

Comment: spring-cloud is including throughout with spring-cloud-starter-oauth2, spring-cloud-starter-feign, spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server, etc. I have client and server on the same server because this app is designed to communicate settings to registered apps and apps can call back to confirm when settings have been applied. so when this service tries to communicate with the JSAPI app, it tries to reach http://JSAPI/customers instead of http://10.0.1.24:8080

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your eureka-client settings?

I believe you would need to set `@FeignClient`'s name (JSAPI in this case) to a mapping in application.yml (or .properties) and not to the service name.

I recently blogged about [Service registration and discovery using Spring Cloud, Eureka, Ribbon, Feign, ...](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/11/14/Microservices-Registration-and-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Eureka-Ribbon-and-Feign.html#load-balancing-requests-using-spring-cloud-feign) but here is an extract of the accompanying source code:

```
@FeignClient(name = ActorsClient.ACTORS_SERVIDE_ID)
public interface ActorsClient {

  String ACTORS_SERVIDE_ID = "the-demo-registration-api-1";
  String ACTORS_ENDPOINT = "/actors";
  String ACTOR_BY_ID_ENDPOINT = "/actors/{id}";
...
```

Demo Service 2’s application.yml

```
...
 eureka:
   client:
     registerWithEureka: true
     fetchRegistry: true
     serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://localhost:8000/eureka/
   instance:
     hostname: ${hostName}
     statusPageUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/info
     healthCheckUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/health
     preferIpAddress: true
     metadataMap:
       instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
 ...
 the-demo-registration-api-1:
   ribbon:
     # Eureka vipAddress of the target service
     DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses: demo-registration-api-1

     #listOfServers: localhost:${SERVER.PORT}
     NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList

     # Interval to refresh the server list from the source (ms)
     ServerListRefreshInterval: 30000
 ...
```

You could see `the-demo-registration-api-1` is a key in yml file mapped to a registered service with name: `demo-registration-api-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress` in your Eureka configuration then the ip instead of the hostname will be used.

If you want to use hostnames you can specify `eureka.instance.hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]}` for example from environment.

More info:
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Brixton.SR6/#_eureka_metadata_for_instances_and_clients

Comment: vcap is cloudfoundry, I run on AWS. What I don't get is that the registry seems just fine. The hostname and ip are the same so really it shouldnt matter which one I use. I don't understand why it's confusing the hostname with apparently the app name/vipAddress (JSAPI). It's not even trying to add the port...

<instance>
            <hostName>10.0.1.24</hostName>
            <app>JSAPI</app>
            <ipAddr>10.0.1.24</ipAddr>